# how to check that any of two lines of a polygon are intersecting(crossing) each other

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I am simply trying to draw a polygon in my android application using google maps and uploading (using a list) the coordinates of the polygon on the local server. My question is before uploading coordinates to the server how can I check that it was a proper polygon (no two lines of the polygon are crossing each other e.g shown in the picture).

[image]

Creating polygon code given below. Thanks

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker))).setTag(counter); 

List<Double> coordinatesInnerMost = new ArrayList<>();
coordinatesInnerMost.add(latLng.longitude);
coordinatesInnerMost.add(latLng.latitude);

polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(latLng);

polygonOptions.add(latLng);
polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255));
polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

Comment: And what is the quedtion?

Comment: Further your code dus not create a polygon but puts a polygon on the map. Show relevant code please.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the problem statement and code, my question is simple that how can we check a polygon that no two of its lines are crossing each other.

Comment: You need some highschool matematics for that.